# Error Code 20 for Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

I have downloaded an application for installing. However, it reported `Error Code 20` during the **install4j Wizard**.

Then I investigated on the log and found the following lines:

```
...
extracting bin\unpack200.exe (size 159296)
... 
untaring JRE was successful
JRE is packed
checking jre\lib\charsets.jar
Unpacking JRE
jre\bin\unpack200.exe -r "jre\lib\charsets.jar.pack" 
"jre\lib\charsets.jar"**
could not create unpack process
--End of the Log--
```

The **unpack200.exe** is extracted from the installer. I checked its size and it looks valid by comparing it with another successful log.

Does anyone know what does the `Error Code 20` mean in **install4j**?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software enabled? Try disabling it and check if the problem persists,

Comment: Hi Indo Kegel, I have tried to disable the anti-virus but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: How can I check? I just download the exe from web.

Comment: Help->About install4j

Comment: Install4j is the program used to pack this installer which I downloaded from web. I don't have Install4j.

Comment: Then you realistically have no way to fix it or investigate the problem. You should contact the vendor.

Comment: Thanks Indo Kegel. I just wonder what does Error Code 20  in Install4j mean because I can't find anyone reporting the same problem with me. 
Is it possible a network problem? Will this error code be different if different version of install4j is used?

Comment: It means that the process could not be created. I mentioned the anti-virus tools because they could cause such a problem.